# Как в angular2 добавить скрипт только для production?

Tags: angular2

Нужно поместить скрипт  в index.html, только для production.

Если добавляю в angular.json:

build: {
...
"scripts": [ "src/myScript.js"],
...
}

добавляется для dev  и prod.
Как сделать так, что бы скрипт добавлялся только в prod? 
Может есть решение стандартными средствами?

Comment: перенеси путь к файлу в `configurations.production.scripts`, там тоже можно объявлять скрипты

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо  [overthesanity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/303477/overthesanity)

Скрипты, стили и прочее можно добавлять непосредственно у режимов dev, stage, prod

```
build: { ... "scripts": [ "src/myScript.js"], ... }
"dev": { ... "scripts": [ "src/myScript.js"], ... }
"prod": { ... "scripts": [ "src/myScript.js"], ... }


 "prod": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],

    "scripts": [
       { "input": "src/metrika.js", "bundleName": "metrika" }
    ]
  }
```

В каждом этапе (build, test, serve) и каждом режиме (prod, dev.stage)